# error execCommand is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload image using input elements with type="file" and then append image to contenteditable fieldset using this code:

```
var doc = document;
function file_upload() {
  var field = doc.getElementById("topic_details"), input = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("input"));
  input.id = "blob";
  input.setAttribute("type", "file");
  input.click();
  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    //reader.onload = function(e) { doc.getElementById("topic_details").innerHTML = "<img style='max-width: 320px; height: auto;' src='"+e.target.result+"' alt='' />"; }
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      field.execCommand("insertImage", false, e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(doc.getElementById("blob").files[0]);
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
  }, false);
}
```

but I recieve this error:

Uncaught TypeError: field.execCommand is not a function

Comment: What's `doc` in `doc.getElementById`?

Comment: I believe `execCommand` is a method only of the `document` object. Not of individual document nodes.

Comment: I define doc as `var doc = document;` in the top of document

Comment: Right, but you're trying to run `execCommand` on `field` which is an individual node.

Comment: ok I replace `field` with `document` and its work but I can't see the image in `field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function file_upload() {
  var field = doc.getElementById("topic_details"), input = doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("input"));
  input.id = "blob";
  input.setAttribute("type", "file");
  input.click();
  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var range = doc.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(field);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
      doc.execCommand("insertImage", false, e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(doc.getElementById("blob").files[0]);
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
  }, false);
}
```

thank you all for help .. cya

Answer (score 3):

i was getting the same error when testing a function which calls the `document.execCommand('copy')` command
what helped me when testing document.execCommand :

i added this line of code at the top of my test.spec.ts file

```
document.execCommand = jest.fn()
```

using angular 9

update: still works in angular 12

Answer (score 0):

First of all `execCommand()` is  a `window` function, that can only be called on the `window` object or its `document`, so it's wrong to call `field.execCommand()` and that's the code behind the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: field.execCommand is not a function

Another thing you are calling `doc.getElementById()` while `doc` is not defined in your `file_upload` function, check that you declared `doc` in a global scope and that it's accessible in `file_upload` function.

**Note:**

Note that it's useless to declare a variable that points to the `document` object, as it's always easy to access it via `document` and it's globally defined in the `window` scope.

Comment: I declared doc as `var doc = document;` in the global scope

Comment: @Haithomy try to log `doc` inside the function and see if it's accessible out there.

Comment: I think he defined the `doc` variable just to reduce typing.

Comment: @Barmar Yes typing an extra 4 characters can be some how, a brain teaser.

Comment: @chsdk We ask for a **Minimal** example. So that saves 20 characters over all the uses. But the assignment is also 20 characters, so it's a wash. :)

Answer (score 0):

document.execCommand('copy') is deprecated and thus not recommended to be used. so I used clipboard API instead of document.execCommand. so no error on clipboard API